# Yii2-Working with multiple check boxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gridview, yii2

I have a `gridview` in which there also a checkbox.

```
    <?= Html::a('Disconnect', ['dco'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id'=>'dco']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Connect', ['rco'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info','id'=>'rco']) ?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <div class="pre-scrollable">
        <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
            return ['value' => $d['msn']];
        }],


        'customer_id',       
        'dept_name:ntext',
        'sub_div_name',
        'division_name',

        'allowed_units',
        'msn',

        'units_consumed',
        [
            'label' => 'Disconnected',
            'attribute' => 'disconnected',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
            'value' => function($model){
                return $model->disconnected == 1 ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'disconnected', [''=>'All','1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No'], ['class' => 'form-control']),
        ],


        'active_energy_total_m',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
        </div>
```

I am using `ajax` for sending checked data to the controller.

There is two buttons `Disconnect` and `Connect`. On the checkbox checked and after clicking any of the two buttons, the corresponding selected item will be connected or disconnected.

```
$DCOurl = Url::toRoute(['/hescolog/dco']);
$RCOurl = Url::toRoute(['/hescolog/rco']);
$(document).ready(function () {      
//DCO 
 $('#dco').on('click',function(e) {


       e.preventDefault();    
 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!=="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});

   // alert(strValue);
$.ajax({
     url: '$DCOurl',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
  });

 });

 $('#rco').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();    
 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!=="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});
    // alert(strValue);
$.ajax({
     url: '$RCOurl',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
  });
  });

  });
```

**Controller**

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
{
   $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
   foreach($data as $value)
   {
      //...... other code
   }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is when I check all the checkboxes and click on any of the buttons, only the 1st checkbox checked an item is connect or disconnect.

Although while checking the controller `` I can see both the items against checkbox checked.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "002995000100 " [1]=> string(13) " 002992002018" }
```

[image]

**Update 1**

Against these two buttons, I have a SOAP service

```
 if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost)
    {
        $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);


        foreach($data as $value)
        {
            $ic++;
            $msn = $value;

            $xml_post_string = /** @lang text */
                '<soapenv:Envelope 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:soap="http://soap.inf.hexing.cn">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
            <soap:doCommand>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <arg0><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RequestMessage
            xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message"
            xmlns:m="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/EndDeviceControls#"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message 
            Message.xsd">
            <Header>
            <Verb>create</Verb>
            <Noun>EndDeviceControls</Noun>
            <Revision>2.0</Revision>
            <Timestamp>2016-01-01T00:00:00+04:30</Timestamp>
            <Source>MDM</Source>
            <AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
      <ReplyAddress>http://ip:port/AmiWeb/services/Metering</ReplyAddress>
            <AckRequired>true</AckRequired>
            <User>
            <UserID>'.$userName.'</UserID>
            </User>
            <MessageID>83c643e6-85c5-43c0-9e0a-fa1deb469b72</MessageID>
            <CorrelationID>1001</CorrelationID>
            <Property>
            <Name>password</Name>
            <Value>'.$password.'</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
            <Name>timeout(m)</Name>
            <Value>30</Value>
            </Property>
            </Header>
            <Payload>
            <m:EndDeviceControls>
            <m:EndDeviceControl>
            <m:reason>Disconnect/Reconnect</m:reason>
            <m:EndDeviceControlType ref="3.0.211.23"/>
            <m:EndDevices>
            <m:mRID>'.$msn.'</m:mRID>
            <m:Names>
            <m:name>Disconnect</m:name>
            <m:NameType>
            <m:name>ControlType</m:name>
            </m:NameType>
            </m:Names>
            </m:EndDevices>
            </m:EndDeviceControl>
            </m:EndDeviceControls>
            </Payload>
            </RequestMessage>
            ]]></arg0>
            </soap:doCommand>
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>';

            $headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
            ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

            $url = $soapUrl;

            // PHP cURL  for https connection

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

            // converting
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $domd=new DOMDocument();


            if(!$domd->loadXML($response)){
                throw new \RuntimeException("failed to parse XML!");
            }
            $inner_xml=$domd->getElementsByTagName("return")->item(0)->textContent;
            if(!($domd2=@DOMDocument::loadXML($inner_xml))){
                throw new \RuntimeException("failed to parse inner_xml!");
            }
            $AsyncReplyFlag=$domd2->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;


            if ($AsyncReplyFlag =='true')
            {
                $ds = 1;

                $disconnected_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                try {
                    Yii::$app->db->createCommand(/** @lang text */
                        "update 
                     `accurate_mam`.`daily_log` 
                     set
                     `disconnected` = '$ds',
                     `diconnected_at` = '$disconnected_at', 
                     `reconnected_at` = NULL
                      where `msn` = '$msn' ;

                       ")->execute(); //update master table

                    Yii::$app->db->createCommand(/** @lang text */
                        "update 
                    `accurate_mam`.`log_disconnected` 
                    set

                    `disconnected_at` = '$disconnected_at' 
                     where `msn` = '$msn'")->execute();// update log disconnected table
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                } // updating the master table
            }


        }

    }
```

I don't know what is the issue and why I am not able to process both the records.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473895/how-i-can-process-a-checkbox-column-from-yii2-gridview/54014265#54014265).  and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283371/how-to-get-more-one-data-from-checkboxcolumn-in-gridview/55310499#55310499) (send the amount using the form in the gridView)

Comment: You can get the value of **CheckboxColumn** in the controller, as well as other Inputs .... by beginForm. (in the gridView and ...)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code it works ok as much as you have posted there isnt anything that would prevent from printing the selected checkboxes, check the console when you click the button for any errors or warnings, and you dont need to provide urls for the buttons `['dco']` just use empty string or `'#.`

Comment: Als using `Yii::$app->request->isPost` instead of `Yii::$app->request->post()` in you controller code will be more relevant and try avoiding `$_POST` when you can `$post=Yii::$app->request->post()`

Comment: @edopro I have tried the solution links that you have provided but I am getting nothing in `Yii::$app->request->post('selection');`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have changed the controller code a bit `if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost)
        {
            $select = Yii::$app->request->post('selection'); //checkbox (array)

            var_dump($select);
            die();}` gives me null

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have updated my code can you please check

Answer (score 1):

**Because you left a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473895/how-i-can-process-a-checkbox-column-from-yii2-gridview/54014265#comment99214949_37473895), I used the beginForm method:**

**in View**

```
<div class="pre-scrollable">
  <?php Pjax::begin() ?>
  <?=Html::beginForm(['test'],'post');?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Disconnect', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name'=>'dco', 'value'=>'dco', 'id'=>'dco','style'=>'margin:0 10px;']) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Connect', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'rco', 'value'=>'rco','id'=>'rco']) ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
            return ['value' => $d['msn']];
        }],

        'customer_id',       
        'dept_name:ntext',
        'sub_div_name',
        'division_name',

        'allowed_units',
        'msn',

        'units_consumed',
        [
            'label' => 'Disconnected',
            'attribute' => 'disconnected',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
            'value' => function($model){
                return $model->disconnected == 1 ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'disconnected', [''=>'All','1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No'], ['class' => 'form-control']),
        ],

        'active_energy_total_m',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>

  <?= Html::endForm();?> 
  <?php Pjax::end() ?>
</div>
```

**in controllers**

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $searchModel  = \Yii::createObject(\app\models\TestSearch::className());
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

  if ( Yii::$app->request->post() ) {

      $arr_select=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');  //An array of selected items (checkbox)
      $dco=Yii::$app->request->post('dco');  // submitButton Disconnect
      $rco=Yii::$app->request->post('rco');  // submitButton Connect

      if ($dco === 'dco') {
           //code for Disconnect here ($query)
           // example:  $modelTest::updateAll(['disconnected' => 1], ['msn' => $arr_select]);
      } elseif ($rco == 'rco') {
           //code for Connect here ($query)
      }

    }

    return $this->render('test', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
    ]);
}
```

You can optimize your code in the controller.

Of course, I think if you use the following method, it is better (a button and ...).

You can easily decide on the controller.

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('action','',[ 'Connect' =>'Connect','Disconnect' =>'Disconnect'],['prompt' => 'Please select','class'=> 'field-black input-sm']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Apply', ['class' => 'btn btn-success','style'=>'margin:0 10px;']) ?>
```

You can place the above code instead of the two `submitButton`. Then decide on the controller according to the `dropDownList` value. Like below:

**also add**:, `'data-pjax'=>''`

```
$_action=Yii::$app->request->post('action'); // dropDown
$arr_select=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection'); //selected items
```

Comment: It helped me.. Cheers :)

Comment: I'm glad. Good luck.